# Reuse of google form triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I automatically create a form with GAS as follows:

```
 var form = FormApp.create(form_name);

 ScriptApp.newTrigger('mysubmit')
 .forForm(form)
 .onFormSubmit()
 .create();
```

The problem is that it creates a trigger every time new form is created.
Is there a way to reuse the same trigger? A problem is that a number of triggers available to my account runs out very quickly.

Comment: I did some research, but didn't find anything obvious to solve your problem.  Can you reuse a form instead of creating lots of new forms?

Comment: No, I need lot's of different forms with one trigger

Comment: How many times do the forms get used?  You could delete old, unused triggers.

Comment: There is limit on triggers per account in google. It equals 20. There is no limit on number of forms though. If I create a form and   add new trigger to it, I can't create more then 20. I need more!!

Comment: Might be better off posting the code to an answer.  The comments can only be edited for 5 minutes, then it's set in stone for eternity; unless you delete the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an Apps Script to create a Form and then create a form submit trigger for that Form, the trigger you have created is attached to the **script**, not the new Form. This is why you are running into the [20 triggers / user / script quota limit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations).

Keep in mind that triggers live on scripts, not Docs, Sheets, or Forms. You can use a script to create a new Form, but you can't use a script to create a new script attached to that Form (scripts cannot create other scripts). This means you cannot programmatically create a trigger that lives on another document.

What you can do is create a Forms add-on that, when a new Form is created, a user can hit a menu control to create a form submit trigger for that Form.

Comment: Thax Ryan. Add-on is not an option unfortunatly, 'cause the user is not supposed to do anything with google form. He has only my interface to access it. So I surrendered and accepted the limit of 20 forms per user.

Answer (score 0):

My workaroung but still 20 triggers limit exists

```
function install_submit_trigger(form, fids)
{
  var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for(var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++)
  {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
  }
  for(var i in fids)
  {
    var fid = fids[i]; 
    try
    {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger('mysubmit')
               .forForm(FormApp.openById(fid.fid))
               .onFormSubmit‌​().create();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
      Logger.log("Error adding trigger: " + e);
    }
  }
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('mysubmit') .forForm(form) .onFormSubmit() .create();
}
```